# Removing duplicated headers in panda (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

Based on below code , I am merging Science and Math based on subtract.

```
for f in Science['Name']:
     Math=(df[df['Name'].str.startswith(f)])
     Math['Sub'] = Math['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w*)', expand=False)
     Field1= pd.merge(Science, Math, left_on='Sub', right_on='Sub')
     
     print(Field1)
```

the result of above code is as below , however I want to *remove repeated headers which are Name-x , Name-y , Sub and Name*. I share my expected result as below, also I want to **store it in a csv file**.

```
    Name_x      Name_y    Sub            Name
0  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-01
1  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-01
2  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-01

    Name_x      Name_y    Sub           Name
0  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-02
1  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-02
2  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-02

    Name_x      Name_y    Sub           Name
0  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-03
1  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-03
2  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-03
```

Expected CSV file:

```
    Name_x      Name_y    Sub           Name
0  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-01
1  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-01
2  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-01
0  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-02
1  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-02
2  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-02
0  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-03
1  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-03
2  Numbers  Math-Numbers  Math         Math-03
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is just concatenate the resulting Dataframes.
i.e.

```
result = []
for f in Science['Name']:
     Math=(df[df['Name'].str.startswith(f)])
     Math['Sub'] = Math['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w*)', expand=False)
     Field1= pd.merge(Science, Math, left_on='Sub', right_on='Sub')
     result.append(Field1)
out_df = pd.concat(result)
print(out_df)
```